# Can not group some of the selected columns

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to pull up the selected columns for each UserID the last Date `DT` he made a purchase.

So I think this is wrong because I can't group by `Purchased, A , S`

```
SELECT UserID, MAX(Date), Purchased, A , S
FROM aramdb
WHERE Purchased > 0 
GROUP BY UserID;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: General GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, or any other dbms that supports window functions, you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY Date DESC)
FROM aramdb
WHERE Purchased > 0 
)
SELECT 
    UserID, Date, Purchased, A , S
FROM Cte
WHERE rn = 1
```